# How can I monitor/sample output audio in Java or C?

Tags: java, c++, c, audio

Lately I have been experimenting with real time visualizations on the audio I play on my computer (via any arbitrary program, such as Spotify) but I've been using SoundFlower to pipe the output audio in to a fake line in.

What I'm wondering is if there is a way that is native to C/C++ or Java that will allow me to capture whatever audio is sent to my computer's (I'm using a Mac) line out in a similar way to how I can capture a line in (I.E. a sample buffer that is continually filled with PCM data).

I have no desire to emulate the other features of SoundFlower except for reading the line out data.

Comment: Asking for a "native" way to capture audio **by definition** is not a library request. Close reason is obviously wrong. Vote to reopen.

Comment: See my answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824663/how-do-i-use-audio-sample-data-from-java-sound/38817181#38817181](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824663/how-do-i-use-audio-sample-data-from-java-sound/38817181#38817181)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest having a look at the source code for [WavTap](https://github.com/pje/WavTap), a fork of SoundFlower, which focusses only on capturing the default audio output of the system.

Both SoundFlower and WavTap work by installing a [kernel extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/Extend/Extend.html), which adds an additional audio device to which audio can be routed. They then captures audio from this device. WavTap makes this the *default* device when it starts so that the overall output of the system is automatically captured without the user having to explicitly set up the routing.

I believe the WavTap code is MIT licensed and the system extension code is well abstracted so you should be able to adapt it for your own project.

To understand a bit more about how this works, the [OS X and iOS Kernel Programming](http://www.apress.com/9781430235361-4892) book has an explanation of some of the techniques in Chapter 12 as well as downloadable code for an example audio device and engine.