# How do I use audio sample data from Java Sound?

Tags: java, audio, javasound, audio-processing, javax.sound.sampled

This question is usually asked as a part of another question but it turns out that the answer is long. I've decided to answer it here so I can link to it elsewhere.

Although I'm not aware of a way that Java can produce audio samples for us at this time, if that changes in the future, this can be a place for it. I know that [`JavaFX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) has some stuff like this, for example [`AudioSpectrumListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioSpectrumListener.html), but still not a way to access samples directly.

---

I'm using `javax.sound.sampled` for playback and/or recording but I'd like to do something with the audio.

Perhaps I'd like to display it visually or process it in some way.

How do I access audio sample data to do that with Java Sound?

See also:

- [Java Sound Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html) (Official)
- [Java Sound Resources](http://web.archive.org/web/20171210140615/http://www.jsresources.org/) (Unofficial)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Well, the simplest answer is that at the moment Java can't produce sample data for the programmer.

[This quote is from the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/controls.html):

> There are two ways to apply signal processing:
>
> - You can use any processing supported by the mixer or its component lines, by querying for `Control` objects and then setting the controls as the user desires. Typical controls supported by mixers and lines include gain, pan, and reverberation controls.
> - **If the kind of processing you need isn't provided by the mixer or its lines, your program can operate directly on the audio bytes, manipulating them as desired.**
>
> This page discusses the first technique in greater detail, because **there is no special API for the second technique**.

Playback with `javax.sound.sampled` largely acts as a bridge between the file and the audio device. The bytes are read in from the file and sent off.

Don't assume the bytes are meaningful audio samples! Unless you happen to have an 8-bit AIFF file, they aren't. (On the other hand, if the samples *are* definitely 8-bit signed, you *can* do arithmetic with them. Using 8-bit is one way to avoid the complexity described here, if you're just playing around.)

So instead, I'll enumerate the types of [`AudioFormat.Encoding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.Encoding.html) and describe how to decode them yourself. This answer will *not* cover how to encode them, but it's included in the complete code example at the bottom. Encoding is mostly just the decoding process in reverse.

This is a long answer but I wanted to give a thorough overview.

---

### A Little About Digital Audio

Generally when digital audio is explained, we're referring to [Linear Pulse-Code Modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) (LPCM).

A continuous sound wave is sampled at regular intervals and the amplitudes are quantized to integers of some scale.

Shown here is a sine wave sampled and quantized to 4-bit:

[image: lpcm_graph]

(Notice that the most positive value in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation is 1 less than the most negative value. This is a minor detail to be aware of. For example if you're clipping audio and forget this, the positive clips will overflow.)

When we have audio on the computer, we have an array of these samples. A sample array is what we want to turn the `byte` array in to.

To decode PCM samples, we don't care much about the sample rate or number of channels, so I won't be saying much about them here. Channels are usually interleaved, so that if we had an array of them, they'd be stored like this:

```
Index 0: Sample 0 (Left Channel)
Index 1: Sample 0 (Right Channel)
Index 2: Sample 1 (Left Channel)
Index 3: Sample 1 (Right Channel)
Index 4: Sample 2 (Left Channel)
Index 5: Sample 2 (Right Channel)
...
```

In other words, for stereo, the samples in the array just alternate between left and right.

---

### Some Assumptions

All of the code examples will assume the following declarations:

- `byte[] bytes;` The `byte` array, read from the `AudioInputStream`.
- `float[] samples;` The output sample array that we're going to fill.
- `float sample;` The sample we're currently working on.
- `long temp;` An interim value used for general manipulation.
- `int i;` The position in the `byte` array where the current sample's data starts.

We'll normalize all of the samples in our `float[]` array to the range of `-1f <= sample <= 1f`. All of the floating-point audio I've seen comes this way and it's pretty convenient.

If our source audio doesn't already come like that (as is for e.g. integer samples), we can normalize them ourselves using the following:

```
sample = sample / fullScale(bitsPerSample);
```

Where `fullScale` is 2<sup>bitsPerSample - 1</sup>, i.e. `Math.pow(2, bitsPerSample-1)`.

---

### How do I coerce the `byte` array in to meaningful data?

The `byte` array contains the sample frames split up and all in a line. This is actually very straight-forward except for something called [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), which is the ordering of the `byte`s in each sample packet.

Here's a diagram. This sample (packed in to a `byte` array) holds the decimal value 9999:

```
  24-bit sample as big-endian:

 bytes[i]   bytes[i + 1] bytes[i + 2]
 ┌──────┐     ┌──────┐     ┌──────┐
 00000000     00100111     00001111

 24-bit sample as little-endian:

 bytes[i]   bytes[i + 1] bytes[i + 2]
 ┌──────┐     ┌──────┐     ┌──────┐
 00001111     00100111     00000000
```

They hold the same binary values; however, the `byte` orders are reversed.

- In big-endian, the more significant `byte`s come before the less significant `byte`s.
- In little-endian, the less significant `byte`s come before the more significant `bytes`.

[WAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) files are stored in little-endian order and [AIFF files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Interchange_File_Format) are stored in big-endian order. Endianness can be obtained from [`AudioFormat.isBigEndian`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.html#isBigEndian--).

To concatenate the `byte`s and put them in to our `long temp` variable, we:

1. Bitwise AND each `byte` with the mask `0xFF` (which is `0b1111_1111`) to avoid [sign-extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) when the `byte` is automatically promoted. (`char`, `byte` and `short` are promoted to `int` when arithmetic is performed on them.) See also [*What does `value & 0xff` do in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11380062/2891664)
2. Bit shift each `byte` in to position.
3. Bitwise OR the `byte`s together.

Here's a 24-bit example:

```
long temp;
if (isBigEndian) {
    temp = (
          ((bytes[i    ] & 0xffL) << 16)
        | ((bytes[i + 1] & 0xffL) <<  8)
        |  (bytes[i + 2] & 0xffL)
    );
} else {
    temp = (
           (bytes[i    ] & 0xffL)
        | ((bytes[i + 1] & 0xffL) <<  8)
        | ((bytes[i + 2] & 0xffL) << 16)
    );
}
```

Notice that the shift order is reversed based on endianness.

This can also be generalized to a loop, which can be seen in the full code at the bottom of this answer. (See the `unpackAnyBit` and `packAnyBit` methods.)

Now that we have the `byte`s concatenated together, we can take a few more steps to turn them in to a sample. The next steps depend on the actual encoding.

### How do I decode `Encoding.PCM_SIGNED`?

The two's complement sign must be extended. This means that if the most significant bit (MSB) is set to 1, we fill all the bits above it with 1s. The arithmetic right-shift (`>>`) will do the filling for us automatically if the sign bit is set, so I usually do it this way:

```
int bitsToExtend = Long.SIZE - bitsPerSample;
float sample = (temp << bitsToExtend) >> bitsToExtend.
```

(Where `Long.SIZE` is 64. If our `temp` variable wasn't a `long`, we'd use something else. If we used e.g. `int temp` instead, we'd use 32.)

To understand how this works, here's a diagram of sign-extending 8-bit to 16-bit:

```
 11111111 is the byte value -1, but the upper bits of the short are 0.
 Shift the byte's MSB in to the MSB position of the short.

 0000 0000 1111 1111
 <<                8
 ───────────────────
 1111 1111 0000 0000

 Shift it back and the right-shift fills all the upper bits with 1s.
 We now have the short value of -1.

 1111 1111 0000 0000
 >>                8
 ───────────────────
 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

Positive values (that had a 0 in the MSB) are left unchanged. This is a nice property of the arithmetic right-shift.

Then normalize the sample, as described in *Some Assumptions*.

#### You might not need to write explicit sign-extension if your code is simple

Java does sign-extension automatically when converting from one integral type to a larger type, for example `byte` to `int`. If you *know* that your input and output format are always signed, you can use the automatic sign-extension while concatenating bytes in the earlier step.

Recall from the section above (*How do I coerce the byte array in to meaningful data?*) that we used `b & 0xFF` to prevent sign-extension from occurring. If you just remove the `& 0xFF` from the highest `byte`, sign-extension will happen automatically.

For example, the following decodes signed, big-endian, 16-bit samples:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    int sample = (bytes[i] << 8) // high byte is sign-extended
               | (bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF); // low byte is not
    // ...
}
```

### How do I decode `Encoding.PCM_UNSIGNED`?

We turn it in to a signed number. Unsigned samples are simply offset so that, for example:

- An unsigned value of 0 corresponds to the most negative signed value.
- An unsigned value of 2<sup>bitsPerSample - 1</sup> corresponds to the signed value of 0.
- An unsigned value of 2<sup>bitsPerSample</sup> corresponds to the most positive signed value.

So this turns out to be pretty simple. Just subtract the offset:

```
float sample = temp - fullScale(bitsPerSample);
```

Then normalize the sample, as described in *Some Assumptions*.

### How do I decode `Encoding.PCM_FLOAT`?

This is new since Java 7.

In practice, floating-point PCM is typically either IEEE 32-bit or IEEE 64-bit and already normalized to the range of `±1.0`. The samples can be obtained with the utility methods [`Float#intBitsToFloat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat-int-) and [`Double#longBitsToDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble-long-).

```
// IEEE 32-bit
float sample = Float.intBitsToFloat((int) temp);
```

```
// IEEE 64-bit
double sampleAsDouble = Double.longBitsToDouble(temp);
float sample = (float) sampleAsDouble; // or just use double for arithmetic
```

### How do I decode `Encoding.ULAW` and `Encoding.ALAW`?

These are [companding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companding) compression codecs that are more common in telephones and such. They're supported by `javax.sound.sampled` I assume because they're used by [Sun's Au format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_file_format). (However, it's not limited to just this type of container. For example, WAV can contain these encodings.)

You can conceptualize [A-law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-law_algorithm) and [μ-law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-law_algorithm) like they're a floating-point format. These are PCM formats but the range of values is non-linear.

There are two ways to decode them. I'll show the way which uses the mathematical formula. You can also decode them by manipulating the binary directly which is [described in this blog post](http://dystopiancode.blogspot.com/2012/02/pcm-law-and-u-law-companding-algorithms.html) but it's more esoteric-looking.

For both, the compressed data is 8-bit. Standardly A-law is 13-bit when decoded and μ-law is 14-bit when decoded; however, applying the formula yields a range of `±1.0`.

Before you can apply the formula, there are three things to do:

1. Some of the bits are standardly inverted for storage due to reasons involving data integrity.
2. They're stored as sign and magnitude (rather than two's complement).
3. The formula also expects a range of `±1.0`, so the 8-bit value has to be scaled.

For μ-law *all the bits* are inverted, so:

```
temp ^= 0xffL; // 0xff == 0b1111_1111
```

(Note that we can't use `~`, because we don't want to invert the high bits of the `long`.)

For A-law, *every other bit* is inverted, so:

```
temp ^= 0x55L; // 0x55 == 0b0101_0101
```

(XOR can be used to do inversion. See [*How do you set, clear and toggle a bit?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47990/2891664))

To convert from sign and magnitude to two's complement, we:

1. Check to see if the sign bit was set.
2. If so, clear the sign bit and negate the number.

```
// 0x80 == 0b1000_0000
if ((temp & 0x80L) != 0) {
    temp ^= 0x80L;
    temp = -temp;
}
```

Then scale the encoded numbers, the same way as described in *Some Assumptions*:

```
sample = temp / fullScale(8);
```

Now we can apply the expansion.

The μ-law formula translated to Java is then:

```
sample = (float) (
    signum(sample)
        *
    (1.0 / 255.0)
        *
    (pow(256.0, abs(sample)) - 1.0)
);
```

The A-law formula translated to Java is then:

```
float signum = signum(sample);
sample = abs(sample);

if (sample < (1.0 / (1.0 + log(87.7)))) {
    sample = (float) (
        sample * ((1.0 + log(87.7)) / 87.7)
    );
} else {
    sample = (float) (
        exp((sample * (1.0 + log(87.7))) - 1.0) / 87.7
    );
}

sample = signum * sample;
```

---

Here's the full example code for the `SimpleAudioConversion` class.

```
package mcve.audio;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat.Encoding;

import static java.lang.Math.*;

/**
 * <p>Performs simple audio format conversion.</p>
 *
 * <p>Example usage:</p>
 *
 * <pre>{@code  AudioInputStream ais = ... ;
 * SourceDataLine  line = ... ;
 * AudioFormat      fmt = ... ;
 *
 * // do setup
 *
 * for (int blen = 0; (blen = ais.read(bytes)) > -1;) {
 *     int slen;
 *     slen = SimpleAudioConversion.decode(bytes, samples, blen, fmt);
 *
 *     // do something with samples
 *
 *     blen = SimpleAudioConversion.encode(samples, bytes, slen, fmt);
 *     line.write(bytes, 0, blen);
 * }}</pre>
 *
 * @author Radiodef
 * @see <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/26824664/2891664">Overview on Stack Overflow</a>
 */
public final class SimpleAudioConversion {
    private SimpleAudioConversion() {}

    /**
     * Converts from a byte array to an audio sample float array.
     *
     * @param bytes   the byte array, filled by the AudioInputStream
     * @param samples an array to fill up with audio samples
     * @param blen    the return value of AudioInputStream.read
     * @param fmt     the source AudioFormat
     *
     * @return the number of valid audio samples converted
     *
     * @throws NullPointerException if bytes, samples or fmt is null
     * @throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
     *         if bytes.length is less than blen or
     *         if samples.length is less than blen / bytesPerSample(fmt.getSampleSizeInBits())
     */
    public static int decode(byte[]      bytes,
                             float[]     samples,
                             int         blen,
                             AudioFormat fmt) {
        int   bitsPerSample = fmt.getSampleSizeInBits();
        int  bytesPerSample = bytesPerSample(bitsPerSample);
        boolean isBigEndian = fmt.isBigEndian();
        Encoding   encoding = fmt.getEncoding();
        double    fullScale = fullScale(bitsPerSample);

        int i = 0;
        int s = 0;
        while (i < blen) {
            long temp = unpackBits(bytes, i, isBigEndian, bytesPerSample);
            float sample = 0f;

            if (encoding == Encoding.PCM_SIGNED) {
                temp = extendSign(temp, bitsPerSample);
                sample = (float) (temp / fullScale);

            } else if (encoding == Encoding.PCM_UNSIGNED) {
                temp = unsignedToSigned(temp, bitsPerSample);
                sample = (float) (temp / fullScale);

            } else if (encoding == Encoding.PCM_FLOAT) {
                if (bitsPerSample == 32) {
                    sample = Float.intBitsToFloat((int) temp);
                } else if (bitsPerSample == 64) {
                    sample = (float) Double.longBitsToDouble(temp);
                }
            } else if (encoding == Encoding.ULAW) {
                sample = bitsToMuLaw(temp);

            } else if (encoding == Encoding.ALAW) {
                sample = bitsToALaw(temp);
            }

            samples[s] = sample;

            i += bytesPerSample;
            s++;
        }

        return s;
    }

    /**
     * Converts from an audio sample float array to a byte array.
     *
     * @param samples an array of audio samples to encode
     * @param bytes   an array to fill up with bytes
     * @param slen    the return value of the decode method
     * @param fmt     the destination AudioFormat
     *
     * @return the number of valid bytes converted
     *
     * @throws NullPointerException if samples, bytes or fmt is null
     * @throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
     *         if samples.length is less than slen or
     *         if bytes.length is less than slen * bytesPerSample(fmt.getSampleSizeInBits())
     */
    public static int encode(float[]     samples,
                             byte[]      bytes,
                             int         slen,
                             AudioFormat fmt) {
        int   bitsPerSample = fmt.getSampleSizeInBits();
        int  bytesPerSample = bytesPerSample(bitsPerSample);
        boolean isBigEndian = fmt.isBigEndian();
        Encoding   encoding = fmt.getEncoding();
        double    fullScale = fullScale(bitsPerSample);

        int i = 0;
        int s = 0;
        while (s < slen) {
            float sample = samples[s];
            long temp = 0L;

            if (encoding == Encoding.PCM_SIGNED) {
                temp = (long) (sample * fullScale);

            } else if (encoding == Encoding.PCM_UNSIGNED) {
                temp = (long) (sample * fullScale);
                temp = signedToUnsigned(temp, bitsPerSample);

            } else if (encoding == Encoding.PCM_FLOAT) {
                if (bitsPerSample == 32) {
                    temp = Float.floatToRawIntBits(sample);
                } else if (bitsPerSample == 64) {
                    temp = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(sample);
                }
            } else if (encoding == Encoding.ULAW) {
                temp = muLawToBits(sample);

            } else if (encoding == Encoding.ALAW) {
                temp = aLawToBits(sample);
            }

            packBits(bytes, i, temp, isBigEndian, bytesPerSample);

            i += bytesPerSample;
            s++;
        }

        return i;
    }

    /**
     * Computes the block-aligned bytes per sample of the audio format,
     * using Math.ceil(bitsPerSample / 8.0).
     * <p>
     * Round towards the ceiling because formats that allow bit depths
     * in non-integral multiples of 8 typically pad up to the nearest
     * integral multiple of 8. So for example, a 31-bit AIFF file will
     * actually store 32-bit blocks.
     *
     * @param  bitsPerSample the return value of AudioFormat.getSampleSizeInBits
     * @return The block-aligned bytes per sample of the audio format.
     */
    public static int bytesPerSample(int bitsPerSample) {
        return (int) ceil(bitsPerSample / 8.0); // optimization: ((bitsPerSample + 7) >>> 3)
    }

    /**
     * Computes the largest magnitude representable by the audio format,
     * using Math.pow(2.0, bitsPerSample - 1). Note that for two's complement
     * audio, the largest positive value is one less than the return value of
     * this method.
     * <p>
     * The result is returned as a double because in the case that
     * bitsPerSample is 64, a long would overflow.
     *
     * @param bitsPerSample the return value of AudioFormat.getBitsPerSample
     * @return the largest magnitude representable by the audio format
     */
    public static double fullScale(int bitsPerSample) {
        return pow(2.0, bitsPerSample - 1); // optimization: (1L << (bitsPerSample - 1))
    }

    private static long unpackBits(byte[]  bytes,
                                   int     i,
                                   boolean isBigEndian,
                                   int     bytesPerSample) {
        switch (bytesPerSample) {
            case  1: return unpack8Bit(bytes, i);
            case  2: return unpack16Bit(bytes, i, isBigEndian);
            case  3: return unpack24Bit(bytes, i, isBigEndian);
            default: return unpackAnyBit(bytes, i, isBigEndian, bytesPerSample);
        }
    }

    private static long unpack8Bit(byte[] bytes, int i) {
        return bytes[i] & 0xffL;
    }

    private static long unpack16Bit(byte[]  bytes,
                                    int     i,
                                    boolean isBigEndian) {
        if (isBigEndian) {
            return (
                  ((bytes[i    ] & 0xffL) << 8)
                |  (bytes[i + 1] & 0xffL)
            );
        } else {
            return (
                   (bytes[i    ] & 0xffL)
                | ((bytes[i + 1] & 0xffL) << 8)
            );
        }
    }

    private static long unpack24Bit(byte[]  bytes,
                                    int     i,
                                    boolean isBigEndian) {
        if (isBigEndian) {
            return (
                  ((bytes[i    ] & 0xffL) << 16)
                | ((bytes[i + 1] & 0xffL) <<  8)
                |  (bytes[i + 2] & 0xffL)
            );
        } else {
            return (
                   (bytes[i    ] & 0xffL)
                | ((bytes[i + 1] & 0xffL) <<  8)
                | ((bytes[i + 2] & 0xffL) << 16)
            );
        }
    }

    private static long unpackAnyBit(byte[]  bytes,
                                     int     i,
                                     boolean isBigEndian,
                                     int     bytesPerSample) {
        long temp = 0;

        if (isBigEndian) {
            for (int b = 0; b < bytesPerSample; b++) {
                temp |= (bytes[i + b] & 0xffL) << (
                    8 * (bytesPerSample - b - 1)
                );
            }
        } else {
            for (int b = 0; b < bytesPerSample; b++) {
                temp |= (bytes[i + b] & 0xffL) << (8 * b);
            }
        }

        return temp;
    }

    private static void packBits(byte[]  bytes,
                                 int     i,
                                 long    temp,
                                 boolean isBigEndian,
                                 int     bytesPerSample) {
        switch (bytesPerSample) {
            case  1: pack8Bit(bytes, i, temp);
                     break;
            case  2: pack16Bit(bytes, i, temp, isBigEndian);
                     break;
            case  3: pack24Bit(bytes, i, temp, isBigEndian);
                     break;
            default: packAnyBit(bytes, i, temp, isBigEndian, bytesPerSample);
                     break;
        }
    }

    private static void pack8Bit(byte[] bytes, int i, long temp) {
        bytes[i] = (byte) (temp & 0xffL);
    }

    private static void pack16Bit(byte[]  bytes,
                                  int     i,
                                  long    temp,
                                  boolean isBigEndian) {
        if (isBigEndian) {
            bytes[i    ] = (byte) ((temp >>> 8) & 0xffL);
            bytes[i + 1] = (byte) ( temp        & 0xffL);
        } else {
            bytes[i    ] = (byte) ( temp        & 0xffL);
            bytes[i + 1] = (byte) ((temp >>> 8) & 0xffL);
        }
    }

    private static void pack24Bit(byte[]  bytes,
                                  int     i,
                                  long    temp,
                                  boolean isBigEndian) {
        if (isBigEndian) {
            bytes[i    ] = (byte) ((temp >>> 16) & 0xffL);
            bytes[i + 1] = (byte) ((temp >>>  8) & 0xffL);
            bytes[i + 2] = (byte) ( temp         & 0xffL);
        } else {
            bytes[i    ] = (byte) ( temp         & 0xffL);
            bytes[i + 1] = (byte) ((temp >>>  8) & 0xffL);
            bytes[i + 2] = (byte) ((temp >>> 16) & 0xffL);
        }
    }

    private static void packAnyBit(byte[]  bytes,
                                   int     i,
                                   long    temp,
                                   boolean isBigEndian,
                                   int     bytesPerSample) {
        if (isBigEndian) {
            for (int b = 0; b < bytesPerSample; b++) {
                bytes[i + b] = (byte) (
                    (temp >>> (8 * (bytesPerSample - b - 1))) & 0xffL
                );
            }
        } else {
            for (int b = 0; b < bytesPerSample; b++) {
                bytes[i + b] = (byte) ((temp >>> (8 * b)) & 0xffL);
            }
        }
    }

    private static long extendSign(long temp, int bitsPerSample) {
        int bitsToExtend = Long.SIZE - bitsPerSample;
        return (temp << bitsToExtend) >> bitsToExtend;
    }

    private static long unsignedToSigned(long temp, int bitsPerSample) {
        return temp - (long) fullScale(bitsPerSample);
    }

    private static long signedToUnsigned(long temp, int bitsPerSample) {
        return temp + (long) fullScale(bitsPerSample);
    }

    // mu-law constant
    private static final double MU = 255.0;
    // A-law constant
    private static final double A = 87.7;
    // natural logarithm of A
    private static final double LN_A = log(A);

    private static float bitsToMuLaw(long temp) {
        temp ^= 0xffL;
        if ((temp & 0x80L) != 0) {
            temp = -(temp ^ 0x80L);
        }

        float sample = (float) (temp / fullScale(8));

        return (float) (
            signum(sample)
                *
            (1.0 / MU)
                *
            (pow(1.0 + MU, abs(sample)) - 1.0)
        );
    }

    private static long muLawToBits(float sample) {
        double sign = signum(sample);
        sample = abs(sample);

        sample = (float) (
            sign * (log(1.0 + (MU * sample)) / log(1.0 + MU))
        );

        long temp = (long) (sample * fullScale(8));

        if (temp < 0) {
            temp = -temp ^ 0x80L;
        }

        return temp ^ 0xffL;
    }

    private static float bitsToALaw(long temp) {
        temp ^= 0x55L;
        if ((temp & 0x80L) != 0) {
            temp = -(temp ^ 0x80L);
        }

        float sample = (float) (temp / fullScale(8));

        float sign = signum(sample);
        sample = abs(sample);

        if (sample < (1.0 / (1.0 + LN_A))) {
            sample = (float) (sample * ((1.0 + LN_A) / A));
        } else {
            sample = (float) (exp((sample * (1.0 + LN_A)) - 1.0) / A);
        }

        return sign * sample;
    }

    private static long aLawToBits(float sample) {
        double sign = signum(sample);
        sample = abs(sample);

        if (sample < (1.0 / A)) {
            sample = (float) ((A * sample) / (1.0 + LN_A));
        } else {
            sample = (float) ((1.0 + log(A * sample)) / (1.0 + LN_A));
        }

        sample *= sign;

        long temp = (long) (sample * fullScale(8));

        if (temp < 0) {
            temp = -temp ^ 0x80L;
        }

        return temp ^ 0x55L;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great will and zest to spread knowledge shown by including every single detail of the subject. +1.

Comment: I'm having issues with this algorithm and 24-bit depths; it works fine with 16 and 32 bits. When I listen to a 24-bit audio (after it's been read by your algorithm), it sounds like there's a huge amount of clipping going on - but I can still vaguely tell it's the same sample. I suspect maybe the values are overflowing some where. Comparison of 16 and 24 bit waveforms (the blue wave is the erroneous 24bit output): https://prnt.sc/sicu84

Comment: I also get an error when trying to instantiate a `SourceDataLine` on this 24bit sample (I don't know yet what this class is used for, I was following the example code from the javadoc). `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface SourceDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian is supported.`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the actual sample data from the currently playing sound. The [other excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26824664/43851) will tell you what the data means. Haven't tried it on another OS than my Windows 10 machine YMMV. For me it pulls the current system default recording device. On Windows set it to "Stereo Mix" instead of "Microphone" to get playing sound. You may have to toggle "Show Disabled Devices" to see "Stereo Mix".

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class SampleAudio {

    private static long extendSign(long temp, int bitsPerSample) {
        int extensionBits = 64 - bitsPerSample;
        return (temp << extensionBits) >> extensionBits;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException {
        float sampleRate = 8000;
        int sampleSizeBits = 16;
        int numChannels = 1; // Mono
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeBits, numChannels, true, true);
        TargetDataLine tdl = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(format);
        tdl.open(format);
        tdl.start();
        if (!tdl.isOpen()) {
            System.exit(1);         
        } 
        byte[] data = new byte[(int)sampleRate*10];
        int read = tdl.read(data, 0, (int)sampleRate*10);
        if (read > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < read-1; i = i + 2) {
                long val = ((data[i] & 0xffL) << 8L) | (data[i + 1] & 0xffL);
                long valf = extendSign(val, 16);
                System.out.println(i + "\t" + valf);
            }
        }
        tdl.close();
    }
}
```