# Check wav format coding

Tags: c#, wav

How can i get wav file format in C# application?
I mean .wav uLaw foramt coding wav files. How can i check this?

Both PCM and uLaw have same bitrate value and KiB value.

8,000 Hz ---8 bit PCM---64---469
8,000 Hz ---µ-Law--------64---469

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you Need to look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19590/WAVE-File-Processor-in-C).

```
/// <summary>
        /// Ensure any given wave file path that the file matches 
        /// with default or base format [16bit 8kHz Mono]
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strPath">Wave file path</param>
        /// <returns>True/False</returns>
        public bool Validate(string strPath)
        {
            if (strPath == null) strPath = "";
            if (strPath == "") return false;

            clsWaveProcessor wa_val = new clsWaveProcessor();
            wa_val.WaveHeaderIN(strPath);
            if (wa_val.BitsPerSample != BIT_PER_SMPL) return false;
            if (wa_val.Channels != CHNL) return false;
            if (wa_val.SampleRate != SMPL_RATE) return false;
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compare two wave files to ensure both are in same format
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Wave1">ref. to processor object</param>
        /// <param name="Wave2">ref. to processor object</param>
        /// <returns>True/False</returns>
        private bool Compare(ref clsWaveProcessor Wave1, ref clsWaveProcessor Wave2)
        {
            if (Wave1.Channels != Wave2.Channels) return false;
            if (Wave1.BitsPerSample != Wave2.BitsPerSample) return false;
            if (Wave1.SampleRate != Wave2.SampleRate) return false;
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brilliant answer by Radiodef on the java side of stack overflow.
[How do I use audio sample data from Java Sound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824663/how-do-i-use-audio-sample-data-from-java-sound)

And here is how the bytes are laid out http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html

Hope that helps!