# Transmit string Array over audio cable using java PCM

Tags: arrays, string, pcm, transmission

My objective is very simple, I want to transmit string data from PC1 to PC2 through an audio cable using the PCM methodology.
However, I'm encountering some problems when I record the data from PC2. In fact I was expecting ASCII numeric values, instead I read values like these:

> 1111000-100111100010211211100222312121222222121111111111000000000-10-2-1-1-1-1-1-10-1-1-1-1-2-2-2-1-2-2-1-1-2-2-2-1-1-10-1-1-1-3-2-2-1-1-1110-10-10-1011110-10011100-20-10000-1000-10-1-1-1000-1-1-1-2-1-1-1-10-10-1-1-2-1-1-1000000101100101110011113121111222312111122111111021111101000010000-1-1-10-1010100110011011111012121110-1-3-5-4-4-7-8-11-15-15-19-23-27-34-38-38-32-28-27-31-33-34-34-32-25-14228568510912212612311811310810396888175747577798079745933-3-47-84-110-116-99-62-162757727264565151525248433735363836302092151421242215109101416123-9-19-22-17-82661-2-4-4-2-3-4-6-8-8-8-8-8-9-11-11-11-10-10-10-11-12-12-11-9-7-8-9-10-8-4030-5-51111710-15-52-90-118-127-121-109-98-94-93-96-93-87-5-5-5-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-7-7-6-6-6-6-7-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-7-5-5-6-6-6-5-6-6-6-5-6-6-5-5-5-6-6-6-5-6-5-5-5-5-4-5-5-5-4-5-5-5-5-5-5-5-4-5-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-3-3-3-4-3-3-3-3-3-2-4-3-2-4-2-2-2-3-3-2-2-3-2-2-2-3-2-3-2-2-2-2-2-2-1-2-1-1-1-1-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-10-2-

here you can find the code that I use to read data from Microphone audio port:

```
public static void Setup_Audio_Read() throws Exception {
    format = null;
    targetInfo = null;
    targetLine = null;
    format = new AudioFormat(Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44000, 8, 1, 1, 44000, true);
    targetInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
    targetLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(targetInfo);
    targetLine.open(format, targetData.length);    //targetLine.open(format,targetLine.getBufferSize());
    targetLine.start();
}

private static long extendSign(long temp, int bitsPerSample) {
    int extensionBits = 64 - bitsPerSample;
    return (temp << extensionBits) >> extensionBits;
}


public static void ReadLineData() throws IOException {
    nBytesRead = targetLine.read(targetData, 0, targetData.length);
}

static public void Read() throws Exception {
    Setup_Audio_Read();
    int waiting_time = 0;
    int bytesread = 0;
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Ale\\Desktop\\Prova\\Token.txt"));
    while (waiting_time < 500) {
        ReadLineData();
        System.out.println(waiting_time);
        long temp = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int bitsPerSample = format.getSampleSizeInBits();
        int bytesPerSample = bytesPerSample(bitsPerSample);
        while (i < nBytesRead) {
            temp = (targetData[i] & 0xffL);
            temp = extendSign(temp, bitsPerSample);
            out.print(temp);
            i = i + bytesPerSample;
        }
        waiting_time +
    }

    out.close();
}
```

as you can see I used the suggestions reported in this forum:
[How do I use audio sample data from Java Sound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824663/how-do-i-use-audio-sample-data-from-java-sound)

but it seems doesn't work.

What do you think? How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Ale

Comment: Ordinary audio cables are analog, you can't transmit binary data accurately over them.

Comment: Make sure the code you post is decently formatted and compiles. E.g. compiler error at line `waiting_time +`